# Slide box up and grayscale behind image on hover and reverse effect on hover loss

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

When hovering over this image, I would like the gray box to appear at the bottom and then slide up. As it slides up, anything it goes over would become grayscale. Then I would like after I move my mouse of the image for gray box to slide back down and remove grayscale as it passes the image.

I got majority of it to work using css only and the only problem I have is when the mouse exits the image I can't figure out how to play the animation back.

Here is what I have tried:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  
  img {
    width: 600px;
    height: 375px;
  }
  
  .hover {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-name: example2;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    display: none;
    
    .gray-image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 600px 375px;
      background-position: bottom 0 left 0;
      
      filter: grayscale(100%);
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
      //position: absolute;
    }
    
    .text {
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.9);
    }
  }
  
  &:hover {
    
    .hover {
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      height: 375px;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    height: 100px;
  }
  to {
    height: 375px;
  }
}

@keyframes example2 {
  from {
    height: 375px;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" />
  
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="gray-image" />
    <div class="slide-box">
      <div class="text">
          <span>This is the title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve my full effect?

Here is also a jsfiddle for those that prefer it: https://jsfiddle.net/pt15ckeL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transition and you can simplify your code like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px; /* control the size */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/* the gray image as pseudo element*/
.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg') 50%/100% auto;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  clip-path: inset(100% 0 0); /* hide it initially */
  transition: 1s;
}
/* your text */
.text {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px; /* center within 100px of height */
  background: linear-gradient(grey 100px,#0000 0); /* color only 100px of height from the top */
  translate: 0 100%; /* slide it so it overflow the wrapper */
  transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover::before {
  clip-path: inset(0); /* reveal the grey image */
}
.wrapper:hover .text {
  translate: 0 0; /* slide back to the top */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    <span>This is the title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is another idea using `backdrop-filter` where you don't need to set the image as background so no url duplication in your code.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px; 
  background: linear-gradient(grey 100px,#0000 0); 
  translate: 0 100%; 
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover .text {
  translate: 0 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    <span>This is the title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, however I wasn't able to make use of the linear-gradient line you have as for some reason my sass compiler throws error due to color only have 4 numbers. So I made my own div in addition to act as a background like that. Plus your way also forced me to have a set height of 100px instead of it being more dynamic and have a min height of 100. But all in all, this solution is amazing, thank you!